# How can I access a kubernetes port forward over a service?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a 2 node cluster where i have deployed a docker image. The docker image provides a restful service which i can access using

`kubectl port-forward my-image 5432:5432`

This allows me to access the REST apis at localhost:5432 . How can I access this over the internet?

I have attempted using `kubectl expose pod my-image --type=NodePort --port=5432 --target-port=5432` but that does not allow connections to $nodeIP:$nodePort

My cluster can access the internet

Comment: is the host your kubernetes cluster is running on accessible from the internet? 
if so, check the created service. kubernetes should have assigned a NodePort. You then access the service via $hostip:$assigned-nodeport not via port 5432

Comment: The nodePort is set as 31527. I cannot access it via $nodeIP:$nodePort

Comment: as asked in above comment "is the host your kubernetes cluster is running on accessible from the internet? "